# how to intergrate my code with jquery cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies

sorry for the poor-explained question before. what i need is to create a cookie which will store some data above some elements on the page, to be speciffic:

1. a div that has the class "checked"
2. a checked-state on a checkbox within that div

ive tried jquery-cookie but i dont understand how to utilize it for my script. this is what i need to store (sorry for the silly code):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.SearchResaultBodyFullUseFulls input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
   $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().toggleClass('checked');
});
});
```

this is the coockie script that i need to use in my site:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
```

how do they connect?

you can see the html page here: http://nelband.com/absolute/AgentSearchResaults.html

what i need is that any div named "SearchResault" will save its toggled "checked" class according to the checked / unchecked state its checkbox

thanks!

Comment: Post your HTML please...

Comment: Although unrelated to the question chaining calls to parent ie $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent() is very brittle, consider using the .parents method with a suitable selector instead ie $(this).parents('#idOfParent').toggleClass('checked');

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I've understood your question, then the following should work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Check for cookie on page load, and set checkbox value accordingly
    if ($.cookie('MyCookie')) {
        $('.SearchResaultBodyFullUseFulls input[type="checkbox"]').attr("checked","checked");
    }

    // Set cookie on change of value
    // You may consider changing this logic to set the cookie on form submission, 
    // however you've not given enough information about your form for me to show this.
    $('.SearchResaultBodyFullUseFulls input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().toggleClass('checked');
        $.cookie('MyCookie', $(this).is(":checked"));
    });
});
```

If you can proved more information about your form (either in a jsFiddle or by posting some HTML) I will be better able to give you a more accurate solution.

Comment: ive added this link - you can see the html page here: http://nelband.com/absolute/AgentSearchResaults.html

what i need is that any div named "SearchResault" will save its toggled "checked" class according to the checked / unchecked state its checkbox